# Using xLookUp in VBA to return range of values

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

I'm attempting to use `Xlookup` in VBA.  I've used it before as a formula in Excel sheets, but I am stuck on getting it to work with returning a range of values in VBA.

For example, the below works fine as `Xlookup` is only returning a single value - the value in column B:

```
Range("E1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(sValue, Range("A:A"), Range("B:B"), "Tag Not Found", 0, 1)
```

As soon as I increase the return range to more than one column, I get nothing returned:

```
Range("E1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(sValue, Range("A:A"), Range("B:C"), "Tag Not Found", 0, 1)
```

Within Excel, this formula would simply put the first value in E1, then 'spill' the second value over into F1.

In the latter example, I see the returned type is variant(1 to 2).  Is there a trick to make this behave like Excel, and simply spill over?

I guess I could put the returned value into a variable, then loop through it and extract each element - but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good idea to return the result of using a worksheet function in VBA to a variable.

The main reason for that would be to check for errors but another is when the result could return multiple values in an array

When an array is returned then you can use `UBound` to get the no of rows and columns and resize the destination range appropriately.

```vb
Dim Res As Variant

    Res = Application.XLookup(sValue, Range("A:A"), Range("B:C"), "Tag Not Found", 0, 1)

    If Not IsError(Res) Then
        If Not IsArray(Res) Then
            Range("E1").Value = Res
        End If
        Range("E1").Resize(UBound(Res,1), UBound(Res,2)).Value = Res
    Else
        MsgBox "XLOOKUP returned an error!", vbInformation
    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

To make things spill dynamically you need a formula.
One of XLOOKUP's tricks is that it can return a Range rather than just values. So try using this formula;

```
Range("e1").Formula2 = "=" & Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(2, Range("A:A"), Range("B:C")).Address
```

Comment: Interesting - what formulas would be returned by code like that?

Comment: something like =b2:c2 in cell E1

Comment: Good answer.  But I don't thinks it's true to say XLookup _can_ return a range.  Rather, it's XLookup  _does_ return a range.  (The classic `Result = XLookup( ... )` then invokes the default `.Value` property to get the result as a value or array.)

Comment: @Chris - I think you are right that XLOOKUP always returns a range even as an in-cell formula (and the range then gets coerced to values when the range enters a cell). In formulas this is usually only noticeable when using a range operator such as : with XLOOKUP, OFFSET INDEX etc